# VueJS: Do not show div if image doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

I am rendering some div and I have like to not show a div when an image is not there.

An example image is here: https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C891283246-preview-480x272.jpg

I am thinking of something like this:

```
<div v-show="twItem.imageurl">{{twItem.title}}</div>
```

But it doesn't work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: probably it because your component render faster than you passing image data to `twItem`, in this case you can define `twItem` as `object` something like this `twItem: {}`

Comment: @DevCl9 there is no error when I use v-if but it doesn't work.

Comment: 'is not there' means the url string is an empty string or the url links for an 404 image?

Comment: @dunhuang when I click on the link https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C891283246-preview-480x272.jpg, I am getting access denied, so it should be access denied.

Answer (score 1):

This task is not primitive.

No matter if you use `v-if` or `v-show`, both compare the same thing, but the result is different. `v-if="false"` will not render the element at all, whilst `v-show="false"` will render it, but hidden. (`display: none;`)

The problem here is, that you simply check if the `twItem.imageurl` is set and NOT if the image was loaded.

What you might be able to do is using `@load`:

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="twItem.loaded">{{ twItem.title }}</div>
  <image :src="twItem.imageurl" @load="twItem.loaded = true">
</template>
```

See here for a more detailed explanation: https://renatello.com/vue-js-image-loaded/

Comment: this would work (+1). OP may also use [this article](https://renatello.com/vue-js-image-loaded/) for more explanation

Comment: Thanks, didnt invest time to look for a thoughrough `@load` explanation. I added it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `v-if` instead of `v-show`.

```
<div v-if="twItem.imageurl">{{ twItem.title }}</div>
```

Comment: Ooops, I've just edited my answer. Try again with `:v-if`. It should work.

Comment: `:` is a short-hand syntax for `v-bind` directive (HTML attribute manipulation). You're essentially writing `v-bind:v-if= ...`.

Comment: :v-if is probably not valid

Comment: Yep, not just probably. `:v-if` is not valid.

Comment: There's no `:` for directives, user directly instead `<div v-if="twItem.imageurl">{{twItem.title}}</div>`